# No display Asus x44h

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, voltage

My laptop is an Asus model x44h. Last night due to high voltages, my charger and laptop were damaged. Now my laptop display shows nothing but I can still hear the login sound. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an external monitor to either always use or for testing.

If the external monitor works, then the chances are your screen is dead!!